VS Code: Is it possible to pass arguments to an integrated terminal profile without quotes?
I'm trying to set up an integrated terminal profile in VS Code (v 1.90.2) to start up PowerShell with a couple arguments.  Here is the block I'm using in my settings.json:
        "powershell": {
            "path": "${env:WINDIR}\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
            "args": [
                "-NoExit",
                "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }

However, when I try to start a terminal, it gives me this error:
-ExecutionPolicy : The term '-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-ExecutionPolicy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I think the problem is that it's passing the arguments to the PowerShell executable with single quotes.  If I mouse over the terminal name on the right side, I can see in the pop-up it says
Command line: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe '-NoExit' '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass'

If I try to run that exact line just hitting Windows+R to get the command prompt and pasting it in, it fails to start.  If I remove the single quotes, it starts up fine.
Is there a way to stop VS Code from encasing those arguments in single quotes when it is instantiating the terminal?

"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass" -> "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"
That is, parameter names and their associated values must be passed as separate array elements.

As for what you tried:
Because each array element is considered a separate argument to pass, "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass" results in exactly this - including the enclosing "..." - being placed on the process command line, i.e. a single argument.
PowerShell doesn't recognize this argument as referring to the -ExecutionPolicy CLI parameter, because parameter names must be unquoted, separate  arguments.
Instead, it treats this string as the value of the default CLI parameter, -Command (-c), and tries to execute it as a command.
The resulting error is the same as if you tried to execute -ExecutionPolicy Bypass in an interactive PowerShell session: -ExecutionPolicy is interpreted as a command name, which obviously doesn't exist.
What Visual Studio Code does when it synthesizes the process command line on Windows is to use quoting around each argument only when needed, and, if so, to use double-quoting ("...").
Quotes are only needed for elements that contain spaces, so that with your original array the following command line is constructed:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass"

You can verify this by executing [Environment]::CommandLine from the new shell process.
What the tooltip in Visual Studio Code shows you is - unfortunately - not the true command line.

Perfect response, thank you so much.  Giving me the BLUF first and then some further details is much appreciated.

My pleasure, @pineconesundae; glad to hear it. Thanks for introducing me to the term BLUF.
